# Call React Parent component function from outside of the Child Component Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

Typically I do the following types of things from a Parent component

```
   this.childZ = React.createRef();  // 

   this.handleTabs = this.handleTabs.bind(this);  // bind a function 

   //Actual function in the parent class component 
   handleTabs = () => { ...}  // I want to call this from Child Component - but outside the class (i have 3rd party javascript etc..

   //In my render()   

   <Tab eventKey={19} title="CORE SEC Z."><SectionZ ref={(secZComponent) => {window.secZComponent.handleTabs() = secZComponent}} handleTabs={this.handleTabs} ref={this.childZ}/></Tab>
```

Notice above I have `SectionZ` which is the child component..   I have function inside   `handleTabs={this.handleTabs}`
and I also have `ref={(secZComponent) => {window.secZComponent.handleTabs() = secZComponent}}` which I have used in the past to allow for some json rendered form data to be able to call a function

Seems that I cannot call parent from the child with either handleTabs={this.handleTabs} or window.....  since it is outside the
class component -->  `class SectionZ extends React.Component { }`

Comment: Trying various things like a function (outside of child class component)  calling  `window.handleTabs();`   but that says `TypeError: window.handleTabs is not a function`

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to accomplish. You are trying to have a function declared in the parent component but called from within a child?

Comment: @jered  -  Yes.   The parent contains all the Tabs in which if i'm on SecZ Child there is a question that if answered Yes, then I need to hide a specific Tab  ( all Tabs on on Parent, and there is a function on parent that on page load will be called already and decides to hide or show the tab.    So that parent function also needs to be thus called from a Child component.    Issue mostly is that all this SurveyJS 3rd party code is outside of my child react component class.

Comment: If you can customize <Tab>, you can use `React.cloneElement` to pass whatever you want to child component,  and receive it as a props.

Comment: @keikai   Do you have an example of doing that?