# how to call direct parent's function by child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components: ComponentA, ComponentB and Home (Home is the component parent). I want to call a function contains in `ComponentA` using a button that is inside of `ComponentB`.

```
const ComponentA= () => {
  const hello=()=>{
    console.log("hello");
  }
  return <></>
})

const ComponentB= () => {
  const callComponentAFunction=()=>{
   // I need call "hello()" from ComponentA
  }
  return 
   <>
    <button onClick={callComponentAFunction}>Call function from ComponentA</button>
   </>
})

const Home= () => {
 return 
  (<>
   <ComponentA>
     <ComponentB />
   </ComponentA>
   </>)
 })
```

How can I call `hello()` function (inside of `ComponentA`) from `ComponentB`?

Comment: Also: [How can I call parent method in a child React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109698/react-call-parent-method-in-child-component/40109797)

Comment: @isherwood please reconsider opening my question. In my scenario I have 3 components. I am a bit confused with the answers you posted. i am new to react.

Comment: This scenario is well documented and fundamental to React. It doesn't warrant another question on SO. Good luck.

Comment: Have you done the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)? It lays things out quite well. You may want to "lift the state" to the parent component instead.